# Nested 2D Table in jQuery, Appending TD to TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I run this through my browser, I get a literal string "<td/>". What is happening here, and how do I get the desired result?

```
<div id="grid">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('asset/json/tictactoe.json',
      function(data)
      {
        $("#grid").append('<table/>');
        var table = $("#grid").find("table");
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; ++i)
        {
          table.append('<tr/>');
          for (var j=0; j<data[i].length; ++j)
          {
            var row = $("#grid").find("table").children()[i];
            row.append('<td/>');
            // row.find("td").html(data[i][j]); *** also, use children here instead of find, because another bug ***
            // add OO events and functionality
          }
        }
      }
    );
  </script>
</div>
```

I am looping through the json object to manipulate the innerHTML of the elements that I create on the fly. I first used JavaScript DOM, which did not have the flexibility I needed to add functionality to make this Tic Tac Toe game.

add: Here is the json

```
[
  ["???","???","???"],
  ["???","???","???"],
  ["???","???","???"]
]
```

add: Here is the HTML outputted from the above jQuery

```
<div id="grid">
<!-- ... some javascript ... -->
<table><tr>&lt;td/&gt;&lt;td/&gt;&lt;td/&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td/&gt;&lt;td/&gt;&lt;td/&gt;</tr><tr>&lt;td/&gt;&lt;td/&gt;&lt;td/&gt;</tr></table></div>
```

Thank you.

add: Solution

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('asset/json/tictactoe.json',
      function(data)
      {
        $("#grid").append('<table/>');
        var table = $("#grid").find("table");
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; ++i)
        {
          $(table).append('<tr/>');
          for (var j=0; j<data[i].length; ++j)
          {
            var row = $(table).children()[i];
            $(row).append('<td/>');
            var td = $(row).children()[j];

            // add the 2D grid from JSON object
            $(td).html(data[i][j]);

            // add OO events and functionality
            // $(td).hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass("hovered"); });
            // $(td).click(function() { $(this).toggleClass("pushed"); });
          }
        }
      }
    );
  </script>
```

Comment: show us your json structure

Comment: have you tried `table.insertRow()` and `row.insertCell()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$` i.e. `$(row).append("<td/>");`

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the TD's in the tables instantly.

Comment: nw. Most of the time, it's better to use the stored element inside the jquery function `$` as that actually tells it to execute jQuery stuff.

Answer (score 0):

is this you wanted?? in loop i created table html data and finally appended to grid.

```html
<div id="grid">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var data = [
  ["???","???","???"],
  ["???","???","???"],
  ["???","???","???"]
];
      function create_Table()
      {
        var table = "<table border='1'>";
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; ++i)
        {
          table +="<tr>";
          for(var j =0; j<data[i].length; ++j){
            table +="<td>"+data[i][j]+"</td>";
          }
          
          $("#grid").html(table);
        }
      }
   create_Table();
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: That "works", but what I really want is to append onclick and onhover events so these cells are clickable, and can look like buttons toggling the border-style: outset, and border-style: inset. So I can go with this, but I want to be able to place the events in the TD's so that it is more OO and less stringy.